# How can I know If a USB 3 device connected to a Linux computer actually uses the SuperSpeed lanes?

Tags: usb, embedded-linux

I've got an embedded platform running Linux on ARM processor.

There is a USB3 camera connected via a USB3 HUB (the kind of Hub that is embedded on a PCB permanently, not the one that you manually connect to your PC).

My goal here is to find out if:
a) the camera actually uses SuperSpeed 
or 
b) just the standard 2.0 speed even though it claims to be 3.0.

What I've already done to find out this is:

`ls -D` gives me such information:

```
     bcdUSB               3.10
     bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
     ...

      bFunctionSubClass       5 USB3 Vision
      iFunction               3 USB3 Vision Device
     ...

  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    ...
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
```

I use wireshark to watch USB packets sent between the host and a USB 3.0 camera. I can see that the camera transfers the image as URB_BULK packets. However, I can't see any details of USB2 or USB3 in wireshark.

The reference: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/u/usb.html
Shows such symbol as usb.speed for example, but I don't see such field in packets visualized in wireshark. Also, I don't know how I would use it as a filter (usb.speed == 1 or usb.speed == 0 won't work).

However, I can see that some of the packets are seen by Wireshark as USB3 Vision protocol packets.

So, How would you use these tools, or any Linux/GNU tools to know if your device which appears in the system as USB3.0 actually uses the wires of USB3.0?

Or, in other words, is the information I'm getting from the OS enough to assume that the device uses USB3 lanes, or is using an oscilloscope the only way to find out?

Comment: Why don't you try "lsusb -t" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to know if your device which appears in the system as USB3.0 actually
> uses the wires of USB3.0?

If a device shows up in the system handle as "USB3", it definitely uses SS lanes, otherwise it will show up as "USB2".

More, if you use a simple command "lsusb -t", it will show you the entire USB device tree with corresponding data rate of the links,  "1.5M" for LS devices, "12M" for FS devices, "480M" for HS devices, "5000M" for USB3 Gen1 device connection, and "10000M" for Gen2 connections.

If a device is USB3 but shows as connected at "480M", then it means that something is wrong with that port, either signal integrity is poor, or connector has wrong/broken plug polarity support.